# javascript async await for function before continuing

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have a helper function that calls other functions. I want the called functions to finish before continuing on in the helper function.

currently they are both changing things at the same time.

```js
helperDikjstras = async() => {
  //do stuff
  await this.colorVisited(visitedNodes); // I want this function to finish before continuing
  await this.colorPath(path);

  //EDIT: I've also tried:
  this.colorVisited(visitedNodes).then(() => this.colorPath(path));
    return;
  }

  colorVisited = async (visitedNodes) => {
    //do stuff
    return;
  }

  colorPath = async (path) => {
    //do stuff
    return;
  }
```

Comment: FYI: empty `return` statements are implied in JavaScript - there is no need to add `return;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course they do, that's the way it works. There is no "interupt" or pause capability in JavaScript. To achieve your goal, call your follow-on functions in the subsequent .then() of the first await.

Like so:

```js
helperDikjstras = async() => {/*...*/}
colorVisited = async(visitedNodes, _callback) => {/*...*/}
colorPath = async(path) => {/*...*/}


helperDikjstras()
  .then(() => colorVisited(blah, halb))
  .then(() => colorPath(somePath));
```

If you needed to have other functions run after `colorPath()` you can simply add more...

```js
helperDikjstras()
  .then(() => colorVisited(blah, halb))
  .then(() => colorPath(somePath))
  .then(() => doSomethingElse())
  .then(() => andAnother())
  .then(() => etc());
```

Comment: Thanks, could you clarify a bit though? I have other functions I want to  call one after another so I want to get this syntax right. is your helpDikjstras supposed the be the function call for helperDiksstras?

I tried: 
``` 
    helperDikjstras = async () => { /*..*/
     
        this.colorVisited(visitedNodes).then(() => this.colorPath(path));
    }
```
but they still run at the same time
`this.colorVisited(visitedNodes).then(() => this.colorPath(path));`

Comment: Yes, `helperDikjstras`. I'll edit the answer. You can continue to add `.then(...)` as many times as necessary. Each function will run in the order listed in the `.then()`s and will wait for the previous function to complete before running.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your answer now, but just to clarify, I can't do this inside another function?
i tried:
`this.colorVisited(visitedNodes).then(() => this.colorPath(path));`
 in my helperDikjstra but they still run at the same time

Comment: In order to run some code X after **asynchronous** code Y, you must use one of the many mechanisms available in JavaScript to wait for Y to complete before running X. Using Promises with Async/Await syntax makes this simple using the technique I supplied. What you latest comment suggests is that you are attempting to run some code X inside (as a function of) the function Y and that breaks the paradigm. So no, you cannot run async code inside another async function and expect the inside one to execute _after_ the enclosing one. I hope all that makes sense.